# Representation-finite symmetric monoid algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Is it known when a monoid algebra over a field is symmetric and representation-finite? For groups the answer is nice, so maybe there is a nice generalisation giving conditions on the field and the monoid?

Answer for groups is that the group algebra is always symmetric and representation-finite if the characteric doesnt divide the order or equals p and divides the order and G has only cyclic p-Sylow groups.

Comment: This is too hard to do. It is equivalent to asking the same for all finite categories. Can you answer this for all monimial algebras

Comment: Yes thats easy. A monomial algebra is symmetric iff it is a symmetric nakayama algebra.

Comment: Is that easy to see from the relations? I know how to characterize these if the monoid  is regular.

Comment: I should say symmetric not representation finite.

Comment: @benjaminSteinberg The result is the same. Selfinjective forces indecomposable projectives to have simple socles. For monomial algebras, thats only possible if the monomial algebra is a nakayama algebra, meaning its quiver is a circle.

Comment: Ok. In any event the algebra of any quiver with relations all of the form $a=0$ or $a-b=0$ is essentially a monoid algebra. Can you say when these are self injectives and Representation finite?

Comment: Well, the classification of selfinjective or symmetric quiver algebras is known. So in principle yes. But of course Im aiming for a nice criterion such as for group algebras instead of some criterion using relations. Maybe replace cyclic Sylow group by "cyclic something else" and add some conditions? But I have no experience with monoid algebras expect from reading some chapters in your book.

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ is a von Neumann regular finite monoid (for each $a\in M$ there is a $b$ with $aba=a$) and $K$ is a field then $KM$ is symmetric and representation finite iff its maximal subgroups have representation finite algebras over $K$ and its sandwich matrices are invertible over the algebras of its maximal subgroups.  In this case $KM$ is isomorphic to a direct product of matrix algebras over the group algebras of its maximal subgroups.

The general case seems to me impossible to say much about.